# Input is not deletable

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a telephone input on my form. It allows numbers only.So I use a simple javascript code to do this.But this time input box cannot be deleted.

```
<form id="aylikal" action="https://web.myadress.co" method="post">
  <table style="height: 116px;" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <input name="adres" required="" style="width: 100%;height: 1px;visibility: hidden;" type="text">
        <td style="width: 590px;"><input name="ad" type="text" placeholder="Ad" required style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 590px;">
          <input name="soyad" type="text" placeholder="Soyad" required style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 590px;">
          <input name="telefon" required type="tel" class="sa" placeholder="(5__) ___-__-__" onkeypress="isInputNumbersa(event)" style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 590px;">
          <button id="pisko" onclick="formyolla()" style="display: inherit;margin: 0 auto;background: #2f889a;color: #FFF;font-size: 20px;padding: 16px 5px;height: auto;border-radius: 5px;width: 100%;">Devam et</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Code

```
function isInputNumbersa(evt) {

  var ch = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);

  if (!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't prevent the user from typing. Instead, let them type and then validate after. Example: I type `123r`, go to backspace the `r` and keep typing `456`... then I get `12456` because your code messed me up. You created a worse user experience than "doing nothing".

Comment: So I need to check after submit. ?

Comment: No, check `onchange` and highlight the field in some way to indicate its invalidity.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: I need to check when user begins the write in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`KeyboardEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated. Use [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Note that although this prevents user from typing letters, it does **not** prevent pasting letters. I'd use a robust library instead.

```js
function isInputNumbersa(e) {
  if (!(/[0-9]/.test(e.key))) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="aylikal" action="https://web.myadress.co" method="post">
    <table style="height: 116px;" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <input name="adres" required="" style="width: 100%;height: 1px;visibility: hidden;" type="text">
          <td style="width: 590px;"><input name="ad" type="text" placeholder="Ad" required style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 590px;">
            <input name="soyad" type="text" placeholder="Soyad" required style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 590px;">
            <input name="telefon" required type="tel" class="sa" placeholder="(5__) ___-__-__" onkeypress="isInputNumbersa(event)" style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 590px;">
            <button id="pisko" onclick="formyolla()" style="display: inherit;margin: 0 auto;background: #2f889a;color: #FFF;font-size: 20px;padding: 16px 5px;height: auto;border-radius: 5px;width: 100%;">Devam et</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: It does.But also any character doesn't paste.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users to only enter numbers then you can use `type="number"`.

```
<input name="telefon" required type="number" class="sa" placeholder="(5__) ___-__-__" onkeypress="isInputNumbersa(event)" style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;">
```

Or if you want to, you can also validate the if the `input` only has numbers using Javascript. Write a method like below and call it using `event listeners`.

```
let input=document.querySelector('.sa');
input.onblur = e => {
    if(isNaN(parseInt(input.innerHTML))){
        alert('Please enter Number');
         input.innerHTML = '';
    }
 }
```

Alternatively you can also use the `pattern` attribute.

```
<input name="telefon" required type="tel" class="sa" placeholder="(5__) ___-__-__" pattern='5[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' onkeypress="isInputNumbersa(event)" style="width: 100%;height: 40px;font-size: 18px;">
```

Comment: The type must be a "tel" for mobile action.